# Where does "The Angels Take Manhattan" fit in timeline?

Tags: doctor-who

Whereabouts in her personal timeline does

> River Song's

appearance in "The Angels Take Manhattan" (Series 7, Episode 5) fit?

It seems that both her and the Doctor's personal timelines both move forward, rather than his moving forward and hers moving backwards which seemed to be the norm.

Comment: I'm not sure why the presence of that particular character in that episode is a spoiler.

Comment: Feel free to edit it. When the question was written the episode had only aired about 12 hours earlier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's near the end. She was Professor Song in this episode, like she was in the Library. The closest we've been to the end of her timeline before this was the Angels two parter in 2005, but even then, she was still Doctor Song.

Comment: But, in the Series 6 DVD extras, don't we see the last night? The night in which The Doctor appears with a new hair cut and gave her the Sonic?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it goes between the Crash of the Byzantium (Time of Angels/Flesh and Stone) and Silence in the Library/Forest of the Dead since she is Professor Song and not "Doctor Song". She references Byzantium as one of her more recent adventures while in the Library but she is a Professor in the library and still "Doctor" (associated with earlier in her time line) while at the Crash of the Byzantium.